# Which is the actual query execution time with Statistic Time enabled in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, query-optimization

When Statistics Time is enabled in the SQL Sever options in SQL Server Management Studio, I get the following information.

> SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 15 ms, elapsed time
>   = 47 ms.
>
> (1745 row(s) affected)
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 31 ms,  elapsed time = 99
>   ms. SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed
>   time = 0 ms.

There are four times in milliseconds. Now, which one is the actual time it took to run the query? They don't seem to be relative.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does SQL Server Execution Times represent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092413/what-does-sql-server-execution-times-represent)

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "the time it took to run the query"

The Parse Time is the time it takes to prepare the query, by syntax checking it, and creating a highly normalized list of tasks.

Copile Time is the time it takes to run the query through the Algerbrizer (this is the component that converts Object names into Object IDs, etc and then choose or create an execution plan for the query.

The time taken for these two phases together is recorded as Parse and Compile Time.

The Execution Time is the time it taken to actually execute or run the compiled plan. Thus, if you mean how long does it take to execute the query, then this is the Elapsed Time under SQL Server Execution Times.

If, however you mean how long does it take for the query to finish, from the instant that I hit execute, then this is the SUM of the Elapsed Time in both the Parse and Compile Time section and also the SQL Server Execution Times section.

The CPU Times (Both for the Parse and Compile section and also the Execution Times section) is the time the processor(s) have spent working on this section. So for calculating duration, the CPU Times can be ignored.